# Swift Xcode 6 push segue table view layout bug

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, segue

For one of my table views, when I activate a push segue on that view, and then return, the layout messes up. The table view moves significantly lower from the top of the screen. I am using the storyboard for all constraints and views. Images attached (or imgur album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQmKF.jpg):

Before Push segue (top right button)
[image: before segue]

During segue
[image: during segue]

After pressing back
[image: after pressing back]

And the storyboard and constraints:
[image: storyboard constraints]

My controller code:

```
import UIKit

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, APINotificationProtocol {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var notifications = NSMutableArray()
var refresher = UIRefreshControl()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    api.delegateNotification = self
    api.getNotifications()
    tableView.reloadData()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString()
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
}

func refresh() {
    api.getNotifications()
    self.refresher.endRefreshing()
}

func didReceiveNotificationResults(results: NSDictionary) {
    var newProducts = results.valueForKey("feed") as NSArray
    notifications = newProducts as NSMutableArray
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   // api.getNotifications()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return notifications.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: NotificationTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("notificationCell") as NotificationTableViewCell
    var alert: NSDictionary = notifications[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    var user: NSDictionary = alert.valueForKey("user") as NSDictionary
    var type: String = alert.valueForKey("type") as String
    var name = user.valueForKey("name") as String
    cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "b&W")
    cell.userImage = gifyImageView(cell.userImage)

    var attributedName = NSMutableAttributedString(string: name)
    attributedName.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 120.0/255.0, green: 69.0/255.0, blue: 193.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), range: NSRange(location:0,length:attributedName.length))
    var url = NSURL.URLWithString(user.valueForKey("avatar") as String)
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 2.0)

    var urlConnection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            var image = UIImage(data: data)
            cell.userImage.image = image
        }
    })

    switch type {
        case "seen":
            var endString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " saw your item")
            attributedName.appendAttributedString(endString)
            cell.alertLabel.attributedText = attributedName
            var product = alert.valueForKey("product") as NSDictionary
            var url = NSURL.URLWithString(product.valueForKey("image") as String)
            var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 2.0)

            var urlConnection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    var image = UIImage(data: data)
                    cell.productImage.image = image
                }
            })
        case "shared":
            var endString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " shared your item")
            attributedName.appendAttributedString(endString)
            cell.alertLabel.attributedText = attributedName
            var product = alert.valueForKey("product") as NSDictionary
            var url = NSURL.URLWithString(product.valueForKey("image") as String)
            var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 2.0)

            var urlConnection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    var image = UIImage(data: data)
                    cell.productImage.image = image
                }
            })
        case "follow":
            var endString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " is now following you")
            attributedName.appendAttributedString(endString)
            cell.alertLabel.attributedText = attributedName
        default:
          println("default")
    }

    cell.dateLabel.text = alert.valueForKey("date") as? String

    return cell
}
```

}

Anyone know what is going on? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post some code, the storyboard only tells us so much. My feeling is that your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and prepareForSegue:sender: might have the info needed to help you out, plus any relevant code from that class. Also, instead of "layout messes up" could you tell us the intended behavior to compare it with witnessed behavior?

Comment: From the limited info you posted in the screenshots, it looks like your table should *always* appear 64 pixels below the top layout guide, so I'm not sure why it doesn't when it's initially shown. And why are there double horizontal and vertical constraints when the root view has only a single child view?